# python Pandas filter columns with specific sub-string in column name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of columns with the following names (using df.columns.values).
I would like to filter out only the columns that contain the value 'EUR'.

How do I do that?

```
array(['EUR10Y', 'EUR12Y', 'EUR15Y', 'EUR1Y', 'EUR20Y', 'EUR25Y', 'EUR2Y',
       'EUR3Y', 'EUR4Y', 'EUR5Y', 'EUR6Y', 'EUR7Y', 'EUR8Y', 'EUR9Y',
       'GBP10Y', 'GBP12Y', 'GBP15Y', 'GBP1Y', 'GBP20Y', 'GBP25Y', 'GBP2Y',
       'GBP30Y', 'GBP3Y', 'GBP4Y', 'GBP5Y', 'GBP6Y', 'GBP7Y', 'GBP8Y',
       'GBP9Y', 'USD10Y', 'USD15Y', 'USD1Y', 'USD20Y', 'USD2Y', 'USD30Y',
       'USD3Y', 'USD4Y', 'USD5Y', 'USD6Y', 'USD7Y', 'USD8Y', 'USD9Y',
       'EUR10Y', 'EUR12Y', 'EUR15Y', 'EUR1Y', 'EUR20Y', 'EUR25Y', 'EUR2Y',
       'EUR30Y', 'EUR3Y', 'EUR4Y', 'EUR5Y', 'EUR6Y', 'EUR7Y', 'EUR8Y',
       'EUR9Y', 'USD1Y', '00USD10Y', '00USD2Y', '00USD3Y', '00USD5Y',
       '00USD7Y'], dtype=object)
```

Thanks and kind regards

Comment: `cols = [x for x in array if 'EUR' in x]` `print(df[cols])`

Comment: A simple list comprehension should do: `[ci for ci in arr if 'EUR' in ci]`. If you wnat to filter on the entire dataframe you can use `df.filter(like='EUR')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use numpy array,

```sh
>>> arr = np.array(
    [
        'EUR10Y', 'EUR12Y', 'EUR15Y', 'EUR1Y', 'EUR20Y', 'EUR25Y', 'EUR2Y',
        'EUR3Y', 'EUR4Y', 'EUR5Y', 'EUR6Y', 'EUR7Y', 'EUR8Y', 'EUR9Y',
        'GBP10Y', 'GBP12Y', 'GBP15Y', 'GBP1Y', 'GBP20Y', 'GBP25Y', 'GBP2Y',
        'GBP30Y', 'GBP3Y', 'GBP4Y', 'GBP5Y', 'GBP6Y', 'GBP7Y', 'GBP8Y',
        'GBP9Y', 'USD10Y', 'USD15Y', 'USD1Y', 'USD20Y', 'USD2Y', 'USD30Y',
        'USD3Y', 'USD4Y', 'USD5Y', 'USD6Y', 'USD7Y', 'USD8Y', 'USD9Y',
        'EUR10Y', 'EUR12Y', 'EUR15Y', 'EUR1Y', 'EUR20Y', 'EUR25Y', 'EUR2Y',
        'EUR30Y', 'EUR3Y', 'EUR4Y', 'EUR5Y', 'EUR6Y', 'EUR7Y', 'EUR8Y',
        'EUR9Y', 'USD1Y', '00USD10Y', '00USD2Y', '00USD3Y', '00USD5Y',
        '00USD7Y'
    ]
)
>>> arr[np.where(np.char.find(arr, 'EUR') >= 0)]
array(['EUR10Y', 'EUR12Y', 'EUR15Y', 'EUR1Y', 'EUR20Y', 'EUR25Y', 'EUR2Y',
       'EUR3Y', 'EUR4Y', 'EUR5Y', 'EUR6Y', 'EUR7Y', 'EUR8Y', 'EUR9Y',
       'EUR10Y', 'EUR12Y', 'EUR15Y', 'EUR1Y', 'EUR20Y', 'EUR25Y', 'EUR2Y',
       'EUR30Y', 'EUR3Y', 'EUR4Y', 'EUR5Y', 'EUR6Y', 'EUR7Y', 'EUR8Y',
       'EUR9Y'], dtype='<U8')
```

Or filter the column names,

```py
selected = df[[col for col in df.columns if 'EUR' in col]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pd.DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html)

```
df.filter(like='EUR')
```